# Как правильно получать ссылку?

Tags: java, android

Как возможно получать такой *формат* картинки у себя в приложении?

> http://img.youtube.com/vi/Rxo0Upfz48Q/0.jpg

При условии что ID-шник всегда будет меняться. Нужно как-то разделить линк на две составляющие?

Answer (score 4):

```
String placeholder = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/%s/0.jpg"

...

String url = String.format(placeholder, id);
```

В `id` должен быть айдишник видео, например `Rxo0Upfz48Q`

Comment: ID-шник я буду получать от пользователя, соответсвенно я не могу занести все значения туда.

Comment: @Inkognito, вот когда получите, запишите его в переменную `id`, и выполните код, который в ответе

Comment: не подскажете как правильно получать ID? в том смысле что пользователь вставил уже линк,  нажал ок к примеру, но я только вывожу Toast. А как вытаскивать  именно ID из ссылки не представляю.

Comment: @Inkognito ну, покажите ссылку, из которой надо вытащить ID. Кроме того, не всегда ID присутствует в ссылке. Я вам в предыдущем вашкм вопросе рассказал, как получить ID

Comment: ну вот к примеру https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rxo0Upfz48Q
и простите не вижу ничего подобного.

Comment: @Inkognito, я уже тоже не могу найти, возможно вопрос удален. Вы можете загрузить страницу по ссылке, и выдрать со страницы такой элемент: `<meta itemprop="videoId" content="Rxo0Upfz48Q">`, в атрибуте `content` находится ID видео

Comment: Ну это опять же для конкретной ссылки пример, разве нет?
а я имел виду, что в приложении получаю каждый раз новый ID-шник, когда пользователь вставляет свою ссылку.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46105/discussion-between-inkognito-and-metalurgus).

Answer (score 1):

Если пользователь загружает видео, то он получит ссылку.
Следовательно можно попробовать использовать `Pattern` а потом `Matcher`.
Что то примерно такое:

```
private static final Pattern rtmpUrlPattern = Pattern.compile("^rtmp://([^/:]+)(:(\\d+))*/([^/]+)(/(.*))*$");
Matcher matcher = rtmpUrlPattern.matcher(url);
host = matcher.group(1);
String portStr = matcher.group(3);
port = portStr != null ? Integer.parseInt(portStr) : 1935;
```

Comment: а какую роль тут играет group?

Comment: ну можно именно записывать/читать именно Rxo0Upfz48Q